# Markdown editor in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, markdown, wmd-editor

I'm looking to use markdown in my website, and I'd like the editor (or something similar to) the one used here at Stackoverflow. As far as I can see, I can get this from the [google code site](http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/).

What I want to know is, how do I then use this in my site? I see perl files etc included with this.

Anyone done this before, or have links to good documentation (the site of the original WMD appears to have disappeared).

Comment: coming soon...https://beegit.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is StackOverflows fork/branch:

- https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/reverse-engineering-the-wmd-editor/
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4168/can-i-use-stack-overflows-reengineered-wmd-editor